# Can't Go Back in Webviews

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

Hello i have a small problem with my project. I have a sliding menu with webviews . But i can't go back in webviews, when i push the button to go back my app just crash. I tryed with OnBackPressed method and OnKeyDown, but no one of this work.  here is my code. just the main activity class and webviewfragment class

Where shoul i put the methods to work fine ? In webview fragment class, not work because webviews extend fragment, no fragmentActivity.

```
package com.pavan.slidingmenu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview ;


    String[] menutitles;
    TypedArray menuIcons; 
    String[] pageUrl;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private List<RowItem> rowItems;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
        pageUrl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageurl);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
            RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                    i, -1), pageUrl[i]);
            rowItems.add(items);
        }

        menuIcons.recycle();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), rowItems);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideitemListener());

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            updateDisplay(0);

        }
    }

    class SlideitemListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            updateDisplay(position);
        }

    }

    private void updateDisplay(int position) {

        String url = rowItems.get(position).getPageUrl();

        Fragment fragment = new MyWebViewFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        setTitle(menutitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


//  @Override
//    public void onBackPressed()
//    {
//        if(webview.canGoBack())
//            webview.goBack();
//        else
//            super.onBackPressed();
//    }

//  @Override
//    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//            switch(keyCode)
//            {
//            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
//                if(webview.canGoBack()){
//                    webview.goBack();
//                }else{
//                    finish();
//                }
//                return true;
//            }
//
//        }
//        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
//    }

}


package com.pavan.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog mProgress;
    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_fragment, container,
                false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        String url = bundle.getString("url");

        webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading",
                "Please wait for a moment...");
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (mProgress.isShowing()) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the Exception that you are getting?

Comment: if i put that 2 methods in webview class, doesn't work because extend fragment, not framentactivity.  How can i do it to work

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make your `WebViewFragment` implement an `Interface`, like this:

```
public interface onBackPressedInterface
{
    public void onBackPressedWebView();
}
```

The only method of the Interface will be implemented on your fragment, so you have to add `implements` clause on your `Fragment` declaration, like this:

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment implements onBackPressedInterface{
```

and implement the method like this:

```
    /**
 * the user presses the back button
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressedWebView()
{
    if (webview.canGoBack()){
        webview.goBack();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).canGoBack=true;
    }
    else{
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).canGoBack=false;
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In your `MainActivity`, add a boolean variable that defines if you make the normal back behaviour or execute the `Interface` method on your `Fragment`. It is public so the Fragment can access it and modify it when there is no more backs to make on the `WebView`. It is true at the begginig so the interface method could be allways called at the first time the user clicks back button.

```
public boolean canGoBack = true;
```

Once the user clicks the back button, the `onBackPressed()` callback is called on your `MainActivity`, so overrite it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(canGoBack)
        ((onBackPressedInterface)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webview_fragment)).onBackPressedWebView();
    if(!canGoBack)
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

`R.id.webview_fragment` is the id of the `fragment` that I have declared in my `Activity` layout file.

So, when the user clicks back button, the fragment method is called, it checks if the webview can go back. If it can, goes back and keeps the Activity boolean true so it can be executed again when a new click occurs.

When the `WebView` has no more backs, the variable is set to false and the normal onBackPressed method is executed, by calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()`.

This is what your `Activity` layout should be like, with one fixed `Fragment` component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/webview_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.pavan.slidingmenu.MyWebViewFragment" />
```

If you do not want to have a fixed `Fragment` in your layout, just create a call in your `MyWebViewFragment` to create an instance of your fragment, like:

`MyWebViewFragment.newInstance()` and call the interface callback on that `Fragment`

Comment: hy @joao2fast4u   i made how you sayed and still not working. back button and app crashed.